# Module with a mage's tower that had miniature exercising golems

Tags: adnd-1e, published-adventures, product-identification

In the late '80s or early '90s I played an AD&D game session centered on a mage's tower that had miniature golems that were constantly exercising (jumping jacks, jogging in place, etc.).  Our GM used a mix of published materials and home-made adventures but I believe this one was a published module.  I believe the tower was set on a seacoast but I wouldn't swear to it.  If I remember correctly, part of the backstory was that the mage hadn't been seen in some time by the locals and it was suspected that he had passed away.  Does anyone recognize this?  Wish I could provide more details but that's about all I recall.

Comment: Hey, could you accept the answer if you like it?  (green check mark). That's how the site knows a question's been answered sufficiently.

Answer (score 9):

Yeah, that's at the end of [C3 The Lost Island of Castanamir](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lost_Island_of_Castanamir), an AD&D 1e adventure for levels 1-4 put out in 1984.  The PCs head out to explore the lair of the disappeared eponymous mage.  It was a RPGA tournament module published later for home use. It had an extremely simple layout, lots of golems and then mostly the usual low-level adventure suspects. Also notable for the introduction of the Gingwatzim, a batch of critters from the Ethereal. You can get it for a modest sum [from various sellers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0880381892).

Comment: Thank you very much.  Maybe I'm seeing through rose-colored glasses but I remember having had a lot of fun playing this one. I've never run across it in any FLGS and, without knowing the name, I've never been able to find it online either.

Comment: You're welcome. Having many bookshelves full of gaming gear back to the early 1980s is paying off!  :-)